# Elasticsearch 5.x D3 integration example fail

Tags: elasticsearch, d3.js

I'm trying an example from https://www.elastic.co/blog/data-visualization-elasticsearch-aggregations
When I try to create indecies and upload data, I get the folllowing error:

```
rolf@PE:~/nfl/scripts/Elasticsearch-datasets-master/mappings$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/nfl?pretty
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "shards_acknowledged" : true,
    "index" : "nfl"
}
rolf@PE~/nfl/scripts/Elasticsearch-datasets-master/mappings$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/nfl/2013/_mapping?pretty -d @nfl_mapping.json
{
    "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
            {
                "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason" : "_index is not configurable"
            }
        ],
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "_index is not configurable"
    },
    "status" : 400
}
```

The start of the mapping file is as follows:

```
{
"2013" : {
    "_index" : {
        "enabled" : true
    },
    "_id" : {
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "store" : "yes"
    },
    "properties" : {
        "gameid" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : "yes"
        }, ...
```

Appreciate some hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using a recent version of ES and the `nfl_mapping.json` mapping is for an older version. In recent versions, it is not possible anymore to specify `_index` and `_id` in your mapping. Change it to this and it will work

```
{
"2013" : {
    "properties" : {
        "gameid" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        }, ...
```

Also change all occurrences of `string` with `text` and `string`+`not_analyzed`to `keyword`.

After that you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that "index" : "not_analyzed" is no longer supported.

Comment: Your answer could also be a comment to the already accepted answer.